# Fullcalendar timeslot height based on content

Tags: fullcalendar, height, ellipsis, timeslots

I would like to expand fullcalendars timeslots height to the content but I do not find in the api how to achieve this. The content is getting ellipsed.

How to switch off fullcalendars content ellipsis?

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in way to do this. You could probably mess with the CSS to increase the height (I think there have been questions about this previously) but to vary the height according to the event content is tricky, not least because the events are not actually children of the timeslots - they are overlaid on top, partly becuase of  course an event will often overlap several timeslots. So how you make those height calculations I'm not sure. You'd have to do a deep dive into the source code and see what can be done.

Comment: from css I got it incrased the timeslot height but I want to switch off the ellipses

Comment: completely? What if someone writes a really long event description which takes up half the page? You want it to stretch all that way down?